# What does the "1:" before the package name mean in yum.log

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I would be very glad if someone could explain what the `1:` before the package name signifies.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1 is the RPM epoch number. It overrides the normal comparison order on version checking. So, if there is some odd reason why you as a packager want to mark a lower version number as an upgrade, you can tag it with an Epoch number.

```
yum info xorg-x11-xauth

Name        : xorg-x11-xauth
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.9
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 30 k
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : X.Org X11 X authority utilities
URL         : http://www.x.org
License     : MIT
Description : xauth is used to edit and display the authorization information
            : used in connecting to an X server.
```

Comment: I notice that not every package has an epoch number.

Comment: @Sajuuk more correctly, a missing epoch number is equal to `0`.